# HTML Object Missing

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a page where a table TR and TD is populated via a JQuery load function. Everything works fine. Following is an actual html that is populated into a table.

```
                <tr>
                <td width="50%" colspan="1" align=left bgcolor=696969>
                    <font style="COLOR: white; FONT: 8pt/11pt verdana">
                        Route Name
                    </font>
                </td>
                <td width="30%" colspan="1" align=right bgcolor=696969>
                    <font style="COLOR: white; FONT: 8pt/11pt verdana">
                        Traffic Percentage
                    </font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="50%" colspan="1" align=left>
                    TRN_01
                </td>
                <td width="30%" colspan="1" align=right id="X1" onclick='opendlg("X1", "70");'>
                    70
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="50%" colspan="1" align=left>
                    RTN_02
                </td>
                <td width="30%" colspan="1" align=right id="X2" onclick='opendlg("X2", "30");'>
                    30
                </td>
            </tr>
```

If you can see I have a function which opens up a dialog which I use to edit the PCT value. Once the dialog is closing, I am trying to update the value of the TD, and I have tried to access them with $("#X2") or with getElimentByID but nothing seems to work. Following is a stripped out version of the code.

```
var dlg;

$(document).ready(function () {

$("#SEL_PFX").change(function() {

$("#TBL_OUTPUT").load("getdata.php?TYPE=3"+"&PARAM1=" + encodeURIComponent($("#SEL_PFX").val()), function() {

                dlg = $("#DLG_PCT_ADJ").dialog({

                    autoOpen: false,
                    height: 200,
                    width: 300,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "Update Value": function () {
                            if ($("#newpct").val() >= 5 && $("#newpct").val() <= 100)
                            {
                                var XTDID = $(this).data("TDID");
                                alert($("#" + XTDID).val());
                            } else {
                                alert('The value must be between 5 and 100');
                            }
                        },
                        Cancel: function () {
                            dlg.dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                });
        });
});

function opendlg(tdid, tdval)
{
    dlg.data('TDID', tdid).data('PCT', tdval).dialog('open');
    $("#newpct").val(tdval);
}
```

Really would love to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Form controls have values. Other elements do not.

Use `.text()` or `.html()`, not `.val()`.